# rand() creating a weird outcome

Tags: c++, arrays, netbeans

When coding for my high school class assignment, I used rand() and realized that it was creating a static outcome. My code is just creating 9 random numbers for arrays and then adding them up.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  srand( time( NULL ) );
  int array[]={0};
  int i = 0;
  while (i<9){
      array[i]={rand()};
      i++;
  }
  int loop=0;
  int sum=0, num=0;
  while (num<9){
  cout<<"Value "<<num<<": "<<array[num]<<"\n";
  sum=sum+array[num];
  num++;
  }

  cout<<"Sum of all values: "<<sum<<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Using this code, some values seem to be the same and others have similarities to the last.
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f99yg.jpg)
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtKNQ.jpg)
[Image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjVT1.jpg) if you look at value 0 and 3, they always have 4 digits, and value 1 is always 0 like how value 2 is always 2. The rest seem to be random. Any idea on why this is happening?

Comment: `rand` sucks. Some implementations of `rand` even  have some bonus quirks. Time to get a C++ book from this decade to supplement that course.

Comment: Try declaring your array to have a size of 9 (like you actually should be): `int array[9]={0};`

Comment: Are you forced to use `rand()`? The modern `<random>` library is better in every single way.

Comment: @scohe001 That worked thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're engaging in an act of undefined behavior since you're accessing the array outside of its bounds.

Declare it with a size of 9 to avoid this:

```
int array[9] = {0};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue is when you define your **int** array, you're defining it as 1 element whose value is 0. So within your while loop, you're already reading from memory out-of-bounds; the values from those dirty addresses are unknown.

```
int array[]={0};
```

To define an integer array, whose length is 9. I recommend using a **#define** or **int const** to define your boundaries. For example, see below

```
#define MAXINDEX 9
...
    int array[MAXINDEX];
    ...
    while (i < MAXINDEX){
    ...
    while (num < MAXINDEX){
    ...
```

or

```
int const MAXINDEX(9);
```